# Custom EAV model in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, eav, custom-attributes, entities

How we can create custom Eav entity and model in magento2. I want to create a custom module where new attributes/fields can be created by user. I will use it to show the details in the grid in admin panel.

I am unable to find any tutorial or reference for this.

Comment: Any news about it? Did you find some useful resource? Thanks

Comment: Yes i figured it out myself. I will post the eav model code soon i am still working on the part where we can create new attribute but eav model is working fine.

Comment: that's great! I look forward to take inspiration from your the code, then.

Comment: @LorenzoS  Check the answer i have posted.

Comment: Use this blog : https://www.rohanhapani.com/create-eav-module-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a module in Github which has custom EAV Model. I have built custom EAV model successfully by following [this module](https://github.com/ksz2013/m2-foggyline-office).
May be it will help someone.

Comment: I'm looking at this module, it seems a nightmare that `InstallSchema.php`. Really you have to create all the eav structure manually?

Comment: @slayerbleast, Yes I agree it is a bit complex but yes this can be a new question. Please ask a new question "how to create eav module setup" and I will share the eav setup of my module.

Comment: @Sarvagya after create custom EAV and attribute for new entity how we can get in custom form in admin. i.e. if I create new attribute with drodown and textbox so how to get automatic in new form?